# Curl to Openshift console to get access token

Tags: openshift

I am trying to retrieve user access token for openshift login. The way I want to achieve is through curl command where user provides his username and password and in response will get the token. I cannot use openshift python client and it has to be a GET/POST call only.

Comment: Hi, the token is saved in kube config file in your local system from where oc get the token `oc whoami -t `

Comment: I want to login from my webpage itself and save the session in javascript, I do not have access to any platform and hence cannot use oc or other related extensions

Comment: @Sachin Is your problem resolved with below solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the below steps

1. Export/Get the token from the curl command

> export TOKEN=$(curl -u user1:test@123 -kI
>   'https://myose01:8443/oauth/authorize?clientid=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token'
>   | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*")

2. Export/Set your endpoint

> export ENDPOINT=myose01:8443

3. Test any of open shift rest call with above two variables

Test sample:-

```
curl -k \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    https://$ENDPOINT/oapi/v1/projects
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm from Red Hat.
This is an old question but the question is still valid today.
Here is how to use curl to get access token.

1. find oauth route, usually it is like "oauth-openshift.apps.."

   `oc get route -n openshift-authentication`
2. curl the found oauth route to retrieve the access token
   for example if you find: "oauth-openshift.apps.ocp4.example.com"

   `curl -u admin -kv 'https://oauth-openshift.apps.ocp4.example.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-challenging-client&response_type=token'`

You will be prompted to enter password.

3. in response you can find "access_token".

Hope that would help.